# What is the difference between '&self' and '&'a self'?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

I recently had an error which was simply resolved by changing

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(&'a self, path: &str) -> Boo<'a> { /* */ }
}
```

to

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(&self, path: &str) -> Boo { /* */ }
}
```

which did not make sense according to my understanding, as I thought that the second version is exactly the same as the first with applied lifetime elision.

---

In case we introduce a new lifetime for the method this seems to be the case according this example from the [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html).

```
fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T;                        // elided
fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut T;              // expanded
```

So what are the differences between this and my first code snipped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lifetime `'a` in `fn foo(&'a self, ...) ...` is defined for `impl<'a>`, that is it is the same for all `foo` calls.

Lifetime `'a` in `fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) ...` is defined for the function. Different calls of `get_mut` can have different values for `'a`.

Your code

> ```
> impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
>     fn foo(&'a self, path: &str) -> Boo<'a> { /* */ }
> }
> ```

is not the expansion of elided lifetime. This code ties lifetime of borrow `&'a self` to the lifetime of structure `Foo<'a>`. If `Foo<'a>` is invariant over `'a`, then `self` should remain borrowed as long as `'a`.

Correct expansion of elided lifetime is

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn foo<'b>(&'b self, path: &str) -> Boo<'b> { /* */ }
}
```

This code doesn't depend on variance of structure `Foo` to be able to borrow `self` for shorter lifetimes.

Example of differences between variant and invariant structures.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Variant<'a>(&'a u32);

struct Invariant<'a>(Cell<&'a u32>);

impl<'a> Variant<'a> {
    fn foo(&'a self) -> &'a u32 {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<'a> Invariant<'a> {
    fn foo(&'a self) -> &'a u32 {
        self.0.get()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = 0;
    let mut variant = Variant(&val);// variant: Variant<'long>
    let mut invariant = Invariant(Cell::new(&val));// invariant: Invariant<'long>
    {
        let r = variant.foo();
        // Pseudocode to explain what happens here
        // let r: &'short u32 = Variant::<'short>::foo(&'short variant);
        // Borrow of `variant` ends here, as it was borrowed for `'short` lifetime

        // Compiler can do this conversion, because `Variant<'long>` is
        // subtype of Variant<'short> and `&T` is variant over `T`
        // thus `variant` of type `Variant<'long>` can be passed into the function 
        // Variant::<'short>::foo(&'short Variant<'short>)
    }
    // variant is not borrowed here
    variant = Variant(&val);

    {
        let r = invariant.foo();
        // compiler can't shorten lifetime of `Invariant`
        // thus `invariant` is borrowed for `'long` lifetime
    }
    // Error. invariant is still borrowed here
    //invariant = Invariant(Cell::new(&val));
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3dd956a3aedcfc68caafb658f80616ce&version=stable)

Comment: Second variant tells the compiler that `Boo<'b>` should live as long as borrow `&'b self`. That is when `Boo<'b>` is no longer in lexical scope where it was taken, `self` is no longer borrowed.

Comment: First variant ties lifetime of borrow `&'a self` to the lifetime of structure `Foo<'a>`. If `Foo<'a>` is [invariant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance) over `'a`, it means that `self` should remain borrowed as long as `'a`.

Comment: I added a bit of explanation why variance of `Foo` affects your code.

Comment: great, now I understand why I failed at creating a MVCE. My original struct contained something which prevents it from being variant while my test structs only contained `&str` which does not prevent variance.