# Lifetime issue with generic parameter with associated type

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am encountering an issue where the compiler says that data is borrowed mutably more than once. I am borrowing the data in a loop, however the borrows are only used locally in the loop, and so the next iteration the borrow should have finished.

The (for me) confusing thing is, that it works for a local variable, but not when the borrow happens through a method defined in a trait, and the variable is passed as a mutable reference to a generic typed parameter that is bounded to that trait.

The following code is a simplified example, but shows the exact same error:

```
trait GetElem<'a, T> {
    type ElemRef: Deref<Target=T>;

    fn get_at(&'a mut self, index: usize) -> Self::ElemRef;
}

struct Ref<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<'a, T> Deref for Ref<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> GetElem<'a, T> for Vec<T> {
    type ElemRef = Ref<'a, T>;

    fn get_at(&'a mut self, index: usize) -> Self::ElemRef {
        Ref(self.get(index).unwrap())
    }
}

fn test<'a, C: 'a + GetElem<'a, i32>>(passed_data: &'a mut C) {
    let mut local_data = vec![1, 2];

    let x = local_data.get_at(0);
    let tmp = *x;
    let y = local_data.get_at(1);
    let _ = tmp + *y;

    let x = passed_data.get_at(0);
    let tmp = *x;
    let y = passed_data.get_at(1);
    let _ = tmp + *y;
}
```

Or see it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a089bfeb0592b960a72c5d4d28bfcf8)

So, in the example, I have both a `passed_data` (which is behind a mutable reference to a type implementing the `GetElem<i32>` trait) and a `local_data`, which is a `Vec<i32>`.

For both, I attempt to do the same thing: get a mutable reference to the first element, copy the value to a temporary variable, get a mutable reference to the second value, and then compute the sum of both.

This works for the `local_data`, but fails for the `passed_data` with the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*passed_data` as mutable more than once at a time
```

Comment: This is why we need [GATs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`&'a mut self` is an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833618/what-is-the-difference-between-self-and-a-self).

You tell the compiler "I borrow `self`, and I can keep the reference alive as long as `'a`". And `'a` is defined in the struct (or the trait), that means you can use the struct only once.

You do not want that. You wanted to say, "I borrow `self`, and I return a type that is related to this borrow". If this was a reference, you wouldn't have a problem. It was `fn get_at<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a T` (which is another antipattern, BTW, downgrade `&mut` to `&`. But there are times you want that). Or just `fn get_at(&mut self) -> &T`, using lifetime elision. If this was a struct, like `Ref<'a, T>`, You also wouldn't have a problem - just return `fn get_mut(&mut self) -> Ref<'_, T>` (or without elision `fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Ref<'a, T>`. But this is not one of those. This is an associated type.

You want to be generic over a lifetime in an associated type. This is called **GAT** (Generic Associated Types). And is not possible in stable Rust, unfortuantely. It *is* possible with nightly:

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

use std::ops::Deref;

trait GetElem<T> {
    type ElemRef<'a>: Deref<Target = T> + 'a
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn get_at(&mut self, index: usize) -> Self::ElemRef<'_>;
}

struct Ref<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<T> Deref for Ref<'_, T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<T> GetElem<T> for Vec<T> {
    type ElemRef<'a>
    where
        T: 'a,
    = Ref<'a, T>;

    fn get_at(&mut self, index: usize) -> Self::ElemRef<'_> {
        Ref(self.get(index).unwrap())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d6812a8568f4eb516f2787ea6e6f12a).

And here's how you use it:

```rust
fn test<C: GetElem<i32>>(passed_data: &mut C) {
    let mut local_data = vec![1, 2];

    let x = local_data.get_at(0);
    let tmp = *x;
    let y = local_data.get_at(1);
    let _ = tmp + *y;

    let x = passed_data.get_at(0);
    let tmp = *x;
    drop(x);
    let y = passed_data.get_at(1);
    let _ = tmp + *y;
}
```

You may wonder why I need `drop()` (a new scope for `x` will do, too, but I prefer this form). Well, there is no reason why I would *not* need. Pre-NLL ([Non-Lexical Lifetimes](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html)), you would need that for references too - the reference drops at the end of the scope, and only then the borrow is free. However, NLL improved this, because if I don't *use* the reference anymore - there isn't a reason to not consider it as dropped. However, with structs this is not true: a struct can implement `Drop` and watch the reference there, and the compiler can't drop it earlier because drop order is guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, with nightly and GAT's enabled it indeed works. With regards to the downgrading of `&mut` to `&`: this is only the case in my simplified example. I actually want to mutate the data using the reference.