# Cannot assign to struct field because it is already borrowed, yet borrowed field is in separate scope

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am running into borrow checker issue. I have a mutable variable. I call a function on it that takes `&self`. Later I try to modify a field of that mutable variable, but the borrow checker protests: "cannot assign to `w.field1` because it is borrowed".

The error message help docs suggest moving the call to the function to a separate scope, however that didn't work.

I included a simplified test scenario that includes some of the other structural elements that may be at play.

```
struct BaseShape<'s> {
   parent: Option<*mut Group<'s>>,
}

struct Circle<'s> {
    shape: BaseShape<'s>,
    radius: f64,
}

struct Group<'s> {
    shape: BaseShape<'s>,
    children: Vec<ShapeWrapper<'s>>,
}

enum ShapeWrapper<'s> {
    Circle(Circle<'s>),
}

struct DataObject<'r, 's> {
    data: &'r ShapeWrapper<'s>,
    computation: bool,
}

impl<'r, 's: 'r> ShapeWrapper<'s> {
    fn inner_compute(&'s self) -> DataObject<'r, 's> {
        DataObject {
            data: &self,
            computation: true,
        }
    } 
}

struct World<'s> {
    items: Vec<ShapeWrapper<'s>>,
    field1: bool,
}

impl<'r, 's: 'r> World<'s> {
    fn compute(&'s self) -> DataObject<'r, 's> {
        let item = self.items.first().unwrap();
        item.inner_compute()
    }
}

pub fn run_main() {
    let item = ShapeWrapper::Circle(Circle {
        shape: BaseShape {
            parent: Option::None,
        },
        radius: 1.0,
    });
    let mut w = World {
        items: vec![item],
        field1: false,
    };

    // ****** separate scope
    {
        let r = w.compute();
        assert_eq!(r.computation, true);
    }

    // ****** why is referenced element still held on here?
    w.field1 = true;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `w.field1` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lifetimes_multiple.rs:60:5
   |
57 |         let r = w.compute();
   |                 ----------- borrow of `w.field1` occurs here
...
60 |     w.field1 = true;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     assignment to borrowed `w.field1` occurs here
   |     borrow later used here
```

Comment: I'm not very proficent at Rust but as far as I understand, you can only have one mutable reference of an object. You can think your reference as w which can be accessed in the entire scope. Maybe try with `let ref = &mut w; ref.compute();` in your sub scope.

Comment: [`&'a self` is an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833618/what-is-the-difference-between-self-and-a-self).

Comment: [Here's a version that compiles.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e3d10cee972cdadcbe763789744e68f) Basically, you wrote `&'s self` but I think you meant `&'r self` (per `DataObject`'s definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful suggestions from Francis Gagné, Chayim Friedman and John Kugelman, the issue was that I was being a little too explicit on the lifetimes. The solution is to only preserve the lifetime signature of the long-lived 's, and keep any other lifetime references anonymous/implicit, thus allowing the compiler to infer the appropriate lifetimes for the shorter-lived references. Here is a portion of the changed code:

```
struct DataObject<'r, 's> {
    data: &'r ShapeWrapper<'s>,
    computation: bool,
}

impl<'s> ShapeWrapper<'s> {
    fn inner_compute(&self) -> DataObject<'_, 's> {
        DataObject {
            data: self,
            computation: true,
        }
    } 
}

struct World<'s> {
    items: Vec<ShapeWrapper<'s>>,
    field1: bool,
}

impl<'s> World<'s> {
    fn compute(&self) -> DataObject<'_, 's> {
        let item = self.items.first().unwrap();
        item.inner_compute()
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you take `&'s self` in `compute()`, you tell the compiler "I may keep `self` borrowed as long as `'s`". `'s` is defined in `World`, and deduced to be the whole lifetime of `w`. So, you borrow `w` for the rest of its life. But then you're trying to use it (borrow it mutably)! You have a mutable and a shared reference to the same object at the same type (as far as the borrow checker is concerned).

See [What is the difference between '&self' and '&'a self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833618/what-is-the-difference-between-self-and-a-self).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had tried something similar before, but the error message made me think I was going down the wrong path. Here is a playground link that shows the resulting error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7430bad1329cdf5980411d97194dab8f